# Is it possible to load screen into Tabs using Vue-router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have a setup where I have a routes file and multiple routes setup e.g: `localhost:8000/test` & `localhost:8000/test2`

My goal is to have a final route for example `localhost:8000/tabs` where I use some sort of Tab import for example bootstrap or Vuetify to crease tabs for each route within the page.

For example: `localhost:8000/tabs?=test&test2` would render a page where the components test and test2 are the tab items. (Components themselves Dynamically retrieved using the routes file?).

The main problem with routes I am facing is that it reloads the page/changes the URL of the page instead of staying within `localhost:8000/tabs`.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can using the `<router-view />` and `child` routes.

**Read more [here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view)**